# How to use binding source filter from one TextBox and Show to another TextBox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable, binding, textbox, bindingsource

I have 2 Textboxes namely TextBoxITC and TextBoxITM. So I've created a keydown event in TextBoxITC so I want to show the result of "ITM" Column in textboxITM.

Thanks

```
 Dim source1 As New BindingSource()
 Private Sub PopulateDatatable()
        Try
            Dim query As String = "Select ITC,ITM FROM IFG WHERE GDN = 'A.04.01.002.001'"
            Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cn)
                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
                    Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                        da.Fill(dt)
                        da.Dispose()
                        source1.DataSource = dt
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch myerror As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub
 Private Sub TextBoxITC_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBoxITC.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Then
            source1.Filter = ""
            TextBoxITC.Clear()
            clearData()
        Else
        End If
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            source1.Filter = "ITC = '" & Replace(TextBoxITC.Text, "'", "") & "'"

            If source1.Count <= 0 Then
                source1.Filter = ""
                TextBoxITC.Clear()
                MsgBox("No Result Found!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have a feeling you might be going about this a little backwards.  Store the dt as a form variable, then use something like a Linq query or datatable.select() to find the row with the matching ITC Value.  Then `textboxITM.Text = DataTable.ITM`  What happens if there are multiple records matching your ITM value?  Or have I over simplified this?

Comment: @Hursey , Thank you for your response. Maybe you can give it as an answer from you

Comment: Probably not, really just proposing a slightly different flow.  I'm not even sure I'm interrupting the question right.  Maybe if you were to update the question with a clear and concise explanation of exactly what you're trying to do and how this isn't working I could have a crack, but as of now your code & explanation has me guessing.  eg Is filtering a Binding source (assuming thats what source1 is) actually what you need to do, or is it just the only way you know to keep that data set in memory?

Comment: @Hursey , Thank you for your response. From the post maybe I've already explained what I want. Thank you very much for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70734885/how-to-display-a-query-in-a-textbox-in-c-sharp-with-connection-of-sql)! and Answer from @Steve

```
 Private Sub TextBoxITC_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBoxITC.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Then
            source1.Filter = ""
            TextBoxITC.Clear()
            clearData()
        Else
        End If
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
              Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cn)
                con.Open()
                Dim query As String = "Select ITM FROM IFG WHERE ITC = ? AND GDN = 'A.04.01.002.001'"
                Using command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)

                    command.Parameters.Add("ITC", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxITC.Text
                    Dim result As Object = command.ExecuteScalar()
                    If result IsNot Nothing Then
                        TextBoxolditem.Text = result.ToString()
                    Else
                        TextBoxolditem.Text = "Number Not found!"
                    End If
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub
```